# center on cluster from outside map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have multiple markers on a map, and I have added the following listener that centers a marker when clicked on.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, count) {
      return function () {
        this.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition() as google.maps.LatLng);
      }
    })(marker, count));
```

I also have the following for centering on a specific marker from outside the map:

```
centerFromTimeline(i){
   google.maps.event.trigger(this.markers[i], 'click');
}
```

which works all well and good, except for when the markers are clustered.  If the marker is hidden in a cluster, centerFromTimeline() will not work cause this.map is null.  Is there a way to center on the cluster in this situation?

Comment: Use a global reference to `map`.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found you can get the clusters and search them for your marker.

```
    let inCluster
    let clusters = await this.markerClusterer.getClusters()
    for(let cluster of clusters){
      let foundMarker = cluster.markers_.find(element => element === this.markers[i]);
      if (foundMarker !== undefined)
        inCluster = true;
        break;
      }
```